# How to add Objects into an array using push method

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, shopping-cart

I want to add an object when I click Add to Cart Button. I want to add cartItems when clicked and want all the cart items into the cart one by one when I click addToCart button. But I don't want to use spread operator for that. I did try push method, but now I am tired of trying. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. I am new in programming.

CART REDUCER -

```
import { actionTypes } from "../../types/actionTypes";

const cartiState = {
  addToCart: [],
};

export const cartReducer = (state = cartiState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.ADD_TO_CART:
      // const singleObject = action.payload; //{...} getting single object on addtocart click
      let x = state.addToCart.push(action.payload);
      return {
        ...state,
        // addToCart: [...state.addToCart, { ...singleObject }],
        addToCart: x,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use the spread operator? Any specific concerns?

Comment: I just want to learn how to do it without spread operator. Because I didn't did it before without spread operator. How people use to do it in es5

Comment: Good practices of Redux dictate that you should pass in a new copy of the existing object instead of mutating an existing object. Moreover, if you just debug your app, you'll see that `x` will contain just a number instead of an array - `Array.push()` returns the new length of the changed array, not its contents. You can try for example `let x = state.addToCart.slice().concat(action.payload);`.